# New Buttons in Interactive Grid toolbar

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I need to add a new button to existing IG toolbar, which will set a specific value in the table column and then save the record.

Is there any way to create new buttons/change the behavior of existing Interactive Grid toolbar buttons?

Comment: Hi Abhinav, did you still need help with this or did Chaitanya’s answer work? If it worked, please accept the answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using APEX 5.1. Yes, you can customise toolbar buttons in an interactive grid. For example, you can  modify the look and feel of the Save and Add Row buttons and also add a Delete button. Select your interactive grid region and in the property editor, enter a value for Advanced > Static ID. Select Attributes > Advanced > JavaScript Initialization Code and input the following:

```
function(config) {
    let $ = apex.jQuery,
        toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(), 
        toolbarGroup = toolbarData.toolbarFind("actions3"); 
        addrowAction = toolbarData.toolbarFind("selection-add-row"), 
        saveAction = toolbarData.toolbarFind("save"); // Save button

    // adding a  "Delete" button
    toolbarGroup.controls.push({type: "BUTTON",
                                action: "selection-delete",
                                icon: "icon-ig-delete", 
                                iconBeforeLabel: true,
                                hot: true
                               });


    // Modifying the buttons
    addrowAction.icon = "icon-ig-add-row"; 
    addrowAction.iconBeforeLabel = true;
    addrowAction.hot = true;

    saveAction.iconBeforeLabel = true;
    saveAction.icon ="icon-ig-save-as"; 
    saveAction.hot = true;


    //storing the config
    config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
    return config;
}
```

Now run the page to see the customisation.

Here's a nice video that shows how to customise IG toolbar.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PBdBAfPBfQ

Comment: I was able to add a custom button, but how to update a table column to to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') upon the button click?